# Calcular input dinamicamente com jquery

Tags: jquery, input, matemática

Boa tarde, possuo um código de inserção de input dinamicamente

```
function new_input() {
        $('<x>'
            + '<input class="cod" id="focus' + rscn +'" placeholder="Código" />'
            + '<input class="desc" placeholder="Descrição" />'
            + '<div class="div"></div>'
            + '<input class="quant" placeholder="Quantidade" />'
            + '<input class="val" placeholder="Valor" />'
            + '<span id="remove_item" class="remove cursor_pointer display_none">+</span>'
        + '</x>').prependTo(scntDiv);
        $('#focus' + rscn).focus();
        rscn++;
        contar_mais('itens_total');
        mask_money();
        return false; }
```

Que ao clicar em novo, insere dentro da div escolhida, todos os inputs que estão programados e ativa a maskmoney e atualiza o valor no input de itens

```
<div id='more_item_add' class='button cursor_pointer display_none'>Novo</div>
<div id='more_item'></div>
<input id='itens_total' class='itens_total' value='0' readonly='readonly' />
```

estou tentando fazer com que ao apertar o TAB ou realizar um event onblur que no caso é tirar o cursor do último input que é o de valor, ele capture a quantidade no input anterior que é o quant e multiplique por o valor dentro do mesmo que é o val e atualize o valor dele com a multiplicação da quantidade por o valor dentro dele

ou seja

eu digito uma quantidade no input quant e aperto o tab para ir para o val e digito o valor dentro dele e aperto o tab para ir para o próximo input e neste evento de sair do input val, o jquery leia a quantidade dentro do quant multiplique pelo valor dentro do val e atualize o val com este novo valor apagando o valor unitário e colocando o valor multiplicado pela quantidade

mais ou menos o que acontece neste exemplo http://jsfiddle.net/QBTN6/2/ mas sem o terceiro input. grato

Edit:

achei este código que modifiquei um bocado e cheguei quase lá, é quase isso que este faz

```
<input class='teste_de_calculo resultado' />
<input class='teste_de_calculo calcula' />

<script>
$('input.teste_de_calculo.calcula').on('blur', function() {
  var v = 0;
  $('input.teste_de_calculo').each(function(i,e) {
    if ($(e).val()) {
      var i = $(e).val().replace(/\,/g,'.');
      if (isNaN(i)) { $(e).val(''); return; }
      v += parseFloat(i);
      $('input.teste_de_calculo.resultado').val(v.toFixed(2)); } }); });
</script>
```

Problema um deste código, ele não funciona se trocar de v += paseFloat(i); para v *= paseFloat(i); ou seja, não multiplica, só soma

Problema dois, só funciona no input 1 não funciona no input 2

Probelma três, como fazer ele funcionar nos inputs dinâmicos

## edit

Com a ajuda do @Leo Caracciolo consegui chegar a quase solução, o código então ficou neste formato

```
function auto_calc_quant() {
    $('.val').blur(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(',','.').replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
        var a = Number(document.getElementById('teste_de_calculo quantidade').value);
        var b = Number(document.getElementById('teste_de_calculo resultado').value);
        if((a != '') && (b != '')) {
            var c = document.getElementById('teste_de_calculo resultado').value = parseFloat(a * b).toFixed(2).replace('.',','); } }); }
```

queria poder fazer o mesmo utilizando classes como no jquery `$('teste_de_calculo resultado').value` sei la, não gosto muito de IDs e executar o calculo sem precisar exatamente fazer blur, tipo, fazer sozinho depois do ultimo change, exemplo, digitei 3,90 ai no 0 ele conta uns 3 segundos e muda o valor sem fazer blur.

Comment: não sei se isso ajudaria em algo, tentei fazer mas não consegui entender https://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/62919-resultado-multiplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-automatico/

Comment: v += paseFloat(i);  vai concatenar e não somar.

Você precisa usar v = v + paseFloat(i);  no lugar.

Comment: Só mudar o evento keyup para blur, tá lá na resposta com os 2 eventos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Com evento keyup**

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.somente-numero').keyup(function (e) {
 $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
   var v1 = Number(document.getElementById("teste_de_calculo resultado").value);
          var v2 = Number(document.getElementById("teste_de_calculo calcula").value);
            if ((v1 !="")&&(v2 !="")){
              var v3 = document.getElementById("teste_de_calculo calcula").value = parseFloat(v1 * v2).toFixed(2);
            }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input class="somente-numero" id='teste_de_calculo resultado' />
<input class="somente-numero" id='teste_de_calculo calcula' />
```

**Com evento blur**

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.somente-numero').blur(function (e) {
 $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
   var v1 = Number(document.getElementById("teste_de_calculo resultado").value);
          var v2 = Number(document.getElementById("teste_de_calculo calcula").value);
            if ((v1 !="")&&(v2 !="")){
              var v3 = document.getElementById("teste_de_calculo calcula").value = parseFloat(v1 * v2).toFixed(2);
            }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input class="somente-numero" id='teste_de_calculo resultado' />
<input class="somente-numero" id='teste_de_calculo calcula' />
```

[Category: Events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

Comment: então, no caso está multiplicando, mas, no input 1, eu precisaria calcular só quando no input 2, no caso não enquanto digita mas sim no blur

Comment: Só mudar o evento keyup para blur, enjoy :)

Comment: de fato, só mudar de keyup para blur, mas, continua no primeiro, o total precisa aparecer no segundo no teste_de_calculo.calcula

Comment: Editei a resposta. Os nomes dos ids dos inputs levam a uma interpretação equivocada ao que você quer. Basta alterar na variável v3  teste_de_calculo resultado por teste_de_calculo calcula

Comment: é que fiz de proposito para que funcionasse, pois não consegui fazer ao contrário, dava erro, ai expliquei na pergunta que era para calcular no segundo, não no primeiro, vou tentar colocar este seu modelo no meu para ver se funcionará, valew

Comment: modificando um pouco, ficou assim 

  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.auto_calc').blur(function (e) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(',','.'));
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
    var v1 = Number(document.getElementById('teste_de_calculo quantidade').value);
    var v2 = Number(document.getElementById('teste_de_calculo resultado').value);
    if ((v1 !='')&&(v2 !='')) {
     var v3 = document.getElementById('teste_de_calculo resultado').value = parseFloat(v1 * v2).toFixed(2).replace('.',','); } }); });
</script>

Comment: agora o problema, como juntar isso no input dinâmico

Comment: Melhor fazer outra pergunta, coloca o código na pergunta e o que você pretende! Aqui já tá ficando confuso.